# Does a component unmounting guarantee to call componentWillUnmount for all the descendants?

Tags: reactjs

It is not clear to me this point, and I wasn't able to find any docs about it.

When a React component is going to be unmounted (i.e. `componentWillUnmount` is called), is there guarantee that all the descendants will be unmounted properly (thus `componentWillUnmount` called as well)?

In other words, during the unmount-phase the entire hierarchy (down the starting node) will be walked or just the exact node to be removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, This is done in the reconciliation process.

> React will recursively mount, update, and **unmount** child components
>   as needed. Once the process resolves to base virtual DOM components,
>   React updates the actual DOM.
>
> Components are unmounted when the parent component is no longer
>   rendered or the parent component performs an update that does not
>   render this instance. ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode will also
>   trigger an unmount.

A reference can be found [here](http://buildwithreact.com/article/component-lifecycle)

Also, React have a different process for composite & DOM components:

- For a user-defined (“composite”) components, unmounting calls a lifecycle method and recurses.
- For "simple" DOM Element, unmounting tells each child to unmount (`child.unmount()`)

See React's implementation details [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/implementation-notes.html#unmounting)

Comment: For the component itself it was clear to me, but your reference points to an interesting _As with other operations, **React recursively unmounts the children**. Finally, React removes the nodes from the DOM and the component lifecycle is complete._

Comment: @MarioVernari - I was also looked at React's implementation notes, there have a different process for composite and DOMcomponents. (edited my answer)

Comment: I think it's fine. I was scared about subscriptions made in some descendants, which have to be **properly** unsubscribed once the main node is removed. Prevent memory-leak, I mean.